# Additional assets aren't compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, assets

In my application js/css file I have no "require_tree" directive. On some page I manually add additional scrip1.js and style1.css files by including them into a view. I've also added those files into "assets.rb"

```
# here
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["script1.js", "style1.css"]


Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["application.js", "application_reactpage.js", "application.css", "react_page/styles.css"]
```

**This works well on localhost.**

But on **production**, even after I compile the assets, those 2 files don't get included into the output compiled js and css files. They're not found. Why is that? How to fix that?

My env on my server is "staging". A part of my staging.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
end
```

**update**

the 2 files do get compiled and saved into "public". But the thing is: a fingerprint isn't added to them on html page. Why not?

Comment: please post production.rb